# How to create a list that results a number from a given list, not the indices?

Tags: python

I am having trouble getting the results to produce the integer in the list, not which index it falls under.

```
#this function takes, as input, a list of numbers and an option, which is either 0 or 1.
#if the option is 0, it returns a list of all the numbers greater than 5 in the list
#if the option is 1, it returns a list of all the odd numbers in the list
def splitList(myList, option):
    #empty list for both possible options
    oddList = []
    greaterList = []
    #if option is 0, use this for loop
    if int(option) == 0:
        #create for loop the length of myList
        for i in range(0, len(myList)):
            #check if index is greater than 5
            if ((myList[i])>5):
                #if the number is greater than 5, add to greaterList
                greaterList.append(i)
        #return results
        return greaterList
    #if option is 1, use this for loop
    if int(option) == 1:
        #create for loop the length of myList
        for i in range(0, len(myList)):
            #check if index is odd by checking if it is divisible by 2
            if ((myList[i])%2!=0):
                #if index is not divisible by 2, add the oddList
                oddList.append(i)
        #return results
        return oddList
```

the results I receive are as follows:

```
>>>splitList([1,2,6,4,5,8,43,5,7,2], 1)
   [0, 4, 6, 7, 8]
```

I am trying to get the results to be [1, 5, 43, 5, 7]

Comment: I'm a fan of tons and tons of commenting, but this is ridiculous.  You shouldn't be at the point where you are literally just rewriting the code in the form of a comment: #if option is 1, use this for loop

Comment: plus python is the most self documenting language Ive ever seen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're iterating over the range of the index. Iterate over the list instead.

```
for i in myList:
    #check if index is greater than 5
    if i >5:
        #if the number is greater than 5, add to greaterList
        greaterList.append(i)
```

So, your code gets rewritten as (with some minor changes)

```
def splitList(myList, option):
    final_list = []
    if int(option) == 0:
        for i in myList:
            if i > 5:
                final_list.append(i)
    elif int(option) == 1:
        for i in myList:
            if i%2 != 0:
                final_list.append(i)
    return final_list
```

You could reduce it by doing

```
def splitList(myList, option):
    if int(option) == 0:
        return [elem for elem in myList if elem > 5]
    elif int(option) == 1:
        return [elem for elem in myList if elem % 2 != 0]
```

Output -

```
>>> splitList([1,2,6,4,5,8,43,5,7,2], 1)
[1, 5, 43, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 2):

List comprehensions greatly simplify your code.

```
def split_list(xs, option):
    if option:
        return [x for x in xs if x % 2]
    else:
        return [x for x in xs if x > 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((myList[i])>5):
    #if the number is greater than 5, add to greaterList
    greaterList.append(i)
```

Instead of adding the index `i`, add the value (`myList[i]`):

```
if ((myList[i])>5):
    #if the number is greater than 5, add to greaterList
    greaterList.append(myList[i])
```

Same thing for the `oddList` case.

---

Note: @Sukrit Kalra's solution is preferable, but I'm leaving this up to show that there's multiple ways of solving this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at your .append() commands... in your compare you're using:

```
if ((mylList[i])%2!=0)
```

or

```
if ((myList[i])>5)
```

...but when you put it into the list, you're just using

```
greaterList.append(i)
```

instead of

```
greaterList.append(myList[i])
```

This must be a homework or class somewhere?